# django admin save_model - assign new value to form field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    basewidth = 650
    img = PIL.Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image_file'])

    if img.size[0] > basewidth:
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

        form.cleaned_data['image_file'] = img

        form.save()
    else:
        form.save()
```

this is still saving the original image, not the resized one.

```
form.cleaned_data['image_file'] = img
```

this line looks wrong. how can I assign the new resized image to form field?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model you can see that `obj` is the model instance. You would need to change `obj.your_image_field` instead of the form field.

Comment: The other place you can do something like this is on the form instead. Write your own form with custom validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-custom-validation

Answer (score 1):

What @Ngenator said is correct. The reason that it is not working for you is that you need to also change form.save() to obj.save()

Here is the code I'm sure will do it:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    basewidth = 650
    img = PIL.Image.open(obj.image_file)

    if img.size[0] > basewidth:
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        obj.image_file = img

    obj.save()
```